# Setting hive configuration properties through hive --service jar

Tags: hive

Can somebody tell me if i can pass hiveconf properties through cli. Actually i want to run a jar using hive  --service jar and in this command i want to set some properties. I have tried the following commands but didnot work:

1. hive --service jar myjar.jar my.example.jar.MyMainClass -hiveconf x=y
2. hive --service jar myjar.jar my.example.jar.MyMainClass HIVE_OPTS x=y

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried -hiveconf as first thing after hive command

Comment: @achyut, can you please provide some example properties for what x can hold?

Comment: @JtheRocker , I was trying to set datanucleus.fixedDatastore=true.

Comment: Why not use export HIVE_OPTS=H$IVE_OPTS "-Ddatanucleus.fixedDatastore=true"? The run your hive job?

Comment: @JtheRocker , Tried that too.. Did not work. Might have done something wrong. I will try again. For now I have fixed it by setting it in code itself.

Comment: @achyut, I didn't see anywhere that a hive client can be invoked this way. You might want to see this link for ways: https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/hiveclient.html .Please ignore this, if this is already known to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, As far as I have seen, it does not work with hive --service jar. **--hiveconf** can be used to set some configuration when launching a CLI, or thrift server.